# Asp.NET Core HealthChecksUI - empty

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes-health-check

I want to configure healthcheckers to work with HealthChecksUI.
But the HealthChecksUI page display a empty list of configured HealthChecks.

Here is code from ConfigureServices Method:

```
services.AddHealthChecksUI();
        services.AddHealthChecks()
            //.AddAzureTableStorage(Configuration["AzureTableStorage"])
            .AddAzureServiceBusQueue(Configuration["NServiceBusParameters"], "CAPIMSPurchaseAPI")
            .AddAzureServiceBusTopic(Configuration["NServiceBusParameters"], "CAPIMSPurchaseAPI")
            .AddCheck("self", c => { return HealthCheckResult.Healthy(); })
            .AddCheck<MailerHealthCheck>("mailer")
            .AddDocumentDb(c =>
            {
                c.UriEndpoint = Configuration["xxxxx"];
                c.PrimaryKey = Configuration["yyyyy"];
            });
```

here is the code from Configure Method:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = registration => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        }
        );
        app.UseHealthChecksUI();
```

Here is the json configuration for HealthChecks-UI:

```
"HealthChecks-UI": {
      "HealthChecks": [
        {
          "Name": "HTTP-Api-Basic",
          "Uri": "http://localhost:4020/health"
        }
      ],
      "Webhooks": [
        {
          "Name": "",
          "Uri": "",
          "Payload": "",
          "RestoredPayload": ""
        }
      ],
      "EvaluationTimeOnSeconds": 10,
      "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
    }
```

When I access the link /health, it show the following result:

```
{"status":"Healthy",
   "totalDuration":"00:00:02.1671415",
   "entries":{  
      "azurequeue":{  
         "data":{  

     },
     "duration":"00:00:01.0486138",
     "status":"Healthy"
  },
  "azuretopic":{  
     "data":{  

     },
     "duration":"00:00:00.1572862",
     "status":"Healthy"
  },
  "self":{  
     "data":{  

     },
     "duration":"00:00:00.0001244",
     "status":"Healthy"
  },
  "mailer":{  
     "data":{  

     },
     "duration":"00:00:00.1451047",
     "status":"Healthy"
  },
  "documentdb":{  
     "data":{  

     },
     "duration":"00:00:00.8158108",
     "status":"Healthy"
      }
   }
}
```

Anyway, the healthcheckers-ui link show an empty list:

What I observed as well is that the healthchecksdb tables are empty.
So it can be that there is a problem with configurations of healthcheckers

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you manage to solve this but for me what worked was to call `AddHealthChecksUI` like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHealthChecksUI("healthchecksdb", settings => settings.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("My health checks", "http://localhost:58811/healthz"));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz",
       new HealthCheckOptions()
       {
         Predicate = _ => true,
         ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
       });
}
```

I had the config set in the `appsettings.json` but it seems like that HealthCheckUI is not reading from there. I am not sure where I should put the config but setting it explictly in `ConfigureServices` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may be missing the UIPath

```
app.UseHealthChecksUI(config =>
        {
            config.UIPath = "/hc-ui";
        })
```

Comment: I added it. And it show the standart heathchecks-ui, but the list doesn't contain any healthcheckers. From what I see, this page is invoking "http://localhost:4020/healthchecks-api", even in my configuration json for healthchecks-ui I have the following configuration:  "Uri": "http://localhost:4020/health"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any configuration inside "launchSettings.json" in Properties Folder?
Something like this? Solved my empty result list.

```
 "HealthChecks": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "healthchecks-ui",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Comment: Created Repo with working sample if needed. https://github.com/jcvpacheco/HealthChecks